# how to make dynamic height div rows using bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am a new user with bootstrap. I have been able to make the multiple div boxes using row-fluid in bootstrap. But now the problem lies if the size of any div box changes dynamically, then also the position of the div box remains the same. I want the position of the boxes relative to the divs around it . Something like what has been implemented on the following websites 
http://www.brainyquote.com/   or  https://storify.com/

After checking their pages, i found that they have actually used absolute positioning and give a specified pixel value to every div box. But i am not able to figure out how..? Can anyone please tell me that how can i do the positioning of my div boxes relative to the boxes around it(primarily at the top of it)?